# Contact Form 7 checkboxes: how to put them in vertical order

Tags: html, css, contact-form-7

In my Contact Form 7 on WordPress, I would like to put checkboxes, only for some specific ones, in this way:

[image]

The [official resource](https://contactform7.com/custom-layout-for-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/) shows a simple css instruction to do it:

```css
span.wpcf7-list-item { display: block; }
```

This instruction I have used it together with an ID selector as Contact Form 7 requires:

```
[checkbox test1 "option1" "option2" "option3" id:namefield]
```

To do that I have create an instruction in css file

```
#namefield.span.wpcf7-list-item { display: block; }
```

It is not working. Using browser inspector the code rendered is taken from /wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/css/styles.css?ver=5.1.9 and it is:

```
span.wpcf7-list-item {
display: inline-block;
margin: 0 0 0 1em;}
```

Instructions from my ID they are not showed.

I'm looking to understand the reason why and what it should better to do to put checkboxes in vertical order.

Answer (score 1):

In WordPress menu, go to appearance -> customize -> custom CSS

Now write below code in custom css area

`span.wpcf7-list-item { display:block; }`

Answer (score 0):

It's working with the code

#namefield span.wpcf7-list-item { display: block; }

without dot after ID